# replace chars only in specific position

Tags: r, regex

How can I tell R to replace string only in given position? The example below does it in any position. Trying to make it work and can't figure out syntax.

```
z <- c("alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_ 0 v1 whiskey 0")
z  #  replace only in pos 25,26  substr(z, 25, 26)
sink('output.txt')
gsub(" 0","**",z)   # <@>><  ??
sink()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it skip 24 characters from the beginning and then test.   Also,   `sub` may be better than `gsub` here.

```
z <- c("alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_ 0 v1")
sub("^(.{24}) 0", "\\1**", z)
[1] "alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_** v1"
```

**Updated string**

```
z2 <- c("alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_ 0 v1 whiskey 0") 
sub("^(.{24}) 0", "\\1**", z2)
[1] "alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_** v1 whiskey 0"
```

Just to be clear, this pattern *only* changes positions 25 and 26. No positions before or after.  It does so by skipping exactly 24 characters from the beginning and then testing for the pattern " 0".  Putting parentheses around `.{24}` cause those first 24 characters to be stored in the variable \1  which is what is used in the "sub" part to put those back.

Comment: Tx G5!!! I think I also need to limit to 25th, as I could have more chars afte rthis, I modified my original test string. z <- c("alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_ 0 v1 whiskey 0").  Trying to understand what is \\1....

Comment: My pattern will only do positions 25 and 26,   not after.  I will add your updated test string.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'ts perfect. \\1 denotes that skipped part ?,  one slash is escape, and \1 denotes it ?  How you call this reference in R, very interesting. Best. M

Comment: More or less, yes.   Let me add that to the answer too.